Locality of Hamiltonian through basis change
Consider a Hamiltonian $H$. For efficient Trotterization, one needs a decomposition into local terms $\sum_j H_j$. However, this is a highly basis-dependent statement. Can I always find a basis representation, defined by a unitary transformation $W$, such that $W H W^\dagger = \sum_j H_j$ with $H_j$ 2-local in the computational basis, i.e. $H_j$ is acting on at most two qubits non-trivially?
In order to understand this better, I tried to formulate this question on the level of eigenvalues. Since $W$ cannot alter the eigenvalues of $H$, there should be information about locality in the spectrum of $H$. So my question might translate into "What are the allowed spectra for 2-local Hamiltonians?"
(One could ask the more general question allowing $k$-locality for an arbitrary, but fixed $k$. Here, for simplicity $k=2$.)
EDIT
I made some (although little) progress understanding this problem and added some learnings from the paper by Cotler et al below. I would be very thankful for further references on the structure of spectra corresponding to local Hamiltonians. Especially, I wonder whether one can prove that local Hamiltonians, although being a null set, lie dense in the space of Hamiltonians and, if yes, how to best approximate a basis in which a given Hamiltonian is $\epsilon$-local.

This paper by Cotler, Penington, and Ranard may be on point. From their abstract "...we can almost always write a Hamiltonian in its local presentation given only its spectrum."

Indeed, this looks very on point. I will have a look, thank you!

After having read the paper by Cotler et al. (thanks again @Mark), I can give at least a partial answer to my question. Unfortunately, the quote

...we can almost always write a Hamiltonian in its local presentation given only its spectrum.

assumes the existence of a local description, so that result is only little help to the question "Given a Hamiltonian/spectrum, is there a local description?" However, the paper contains an interesting and very simple dimension counting argument that explains that almost all Hamiltonians do not have a local description.
For this, define the space $S$ of $k$-local Hamiltonians acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of $n$ qubits that are of the form
$$
H = a_0 \mathbb{I} + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{\alpha=1}^3 a_{\alpha}^i P^\alpha_i + \sum_{i<j}^n \sum_{\alpha, \beta=1}^3 a_{\alpha \beta}^{ij} P^\alpha_i P_{j}^\beta + ...
$$
with the identity $\mathbb{I}$ and single-qubit Pauli operators $P^\alpha_i$. $S$ is a subspace of the linear operators $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ on $\mathcal{H}$. $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ has dimension $N^2 := (2^n)^2$, that grows exponential in $n$, as we all know. But $S$ has dimension
$$
s = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j} 3^j,
$$
which is polynomial in $n$ for constant $k$. As $s<N^2$, $S$ will have positive co-dimension making the space of $k$-local Hamiltonians a null set.
This is not a full answer to my question, as it does not explain how to find out whether a given spectrum has a $k$-local description or not, but it tells us that a randomly drawn Hamiltonian will not be local in any basis.
